# Copy constructor for object with two linked lists C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a copy constructor for an object that has two linked lists. I want to have my copy have know references to the original object. I wrote a copy contructor that makes an exact copy of the original but it still references the original and I can't find where it is doing it. Here is my code.

```
InfiniteBools::InfiniteBools(InfiniteBools* original) {
    if (original == NULL) return;

    //sets the head of copy to new linked list nodes that are copies of original
    InfiniteBools* copy = new InfiniteBools();
    copy->nonNegHeader = new LinkedListNode(original->nonNegHeader->value,NULL);
    copy->negHeader = new LinkedListNode(original->negHeader->value, NULL);

    LinkedListNode* tempPos = original->nonNegHeader;
    LinkedListNode* tempNeg = original->negHeader;
    LinkedListNode* copyTempPos = copy->nonNegHeader;
    LinkedListNode* copyTempNeg = copy->negHeader;

    tempPos = tempPos->next;
    while (tempPos != NULL) {
        // Allocate the next node and set current node next to the new node.
        copyTempPos->next = new LinkedListNode(tempPos->value,NULL);
        copyTempPos = copyTempNeg->next; //move temp to the new node

        tempPos = tempPos->next; //move temp of original foward
    }

    tempNeg = tempNeg->next;
    while (tempPos != NULL) {
        copyTempNeg->next = new LinkedListNode(tempNeg->value, NULL);
        copyTempNeg = copyTempNeg->next;
        tempNeg = tempNeg->next;
    }
}
```

I've tried going through it but I can't find where it's going wrong. If you see what I'm doing wrong please let me know.

Thank you.

EDIT:

---

InfiniteBools is an object that contains reference to two nodes, which are the heads of two linked lists.
Each node or LinkedListNode contains a boolean value and a pointer to the next node.

Comment: That certainly isn't a copy-ctor. Copy-ctors take instance references, not addresses, as arguments. And we have no clue how `InfiniteBools`, nor `LinkedListNode` are actually defined. Consider this: you have a project full of code. we have *only* what you posted here, and *nothing more*.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just wondering: why do you need a linked list here at all? Whatever you do, an implementation based on arrays would probably be more efficient, best use standard containers for: `std::vector<bool>` or, if you want to avoid the specialisation for bool (packing multiple bits together), `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 1):

At first: a copy constructor usually accepts a const reference:

```
InfiniteBools::InfiniteBools(InfiniteBools const& original);
```

Then you *are* constructing a new object already. Why the second internal object? `this` is your copy:

```
//InfiniteBools* copy = new InfiniteBools();
// would have resulted in a memory leak!!!

this->nonNegHeader = new LinkedListNode(original->nonNegHeader->value, nullptr);
this->negHeader = new LinkedListNode(original->negHeader->value, nullptr);
// prefer C++ keyword (nullptr) over (obsolete) C-style macro (NULL)
```

You can leave out `this->`, as long as there is no other variable with same name as your member (the former one then hiding the latter one).

You forgot to check for `original` having empty lists.

Rest of code looks correct at a first glance (be aware, though, that if you have a const reference, you need const pointers for iterating over its list nodes!), did not test explicitly. If you don't copy interleaved, you only need one set of variables. If you write a separate class `LinkedList` wrapping around your nodes, doing the copying in its own copy constructor, you can avoid code duplication.

Actually, there is already a fully implemented linked list: [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). It is doubly linked, if you want a singly linked list, there's [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) as well. You should prefer the ready-for-use implementations over re-inventing the wheel (unless you are doing it for *excersize*...).

Comment: Thank you for helping. If i pass in const& original don't I still need a pointer to the object in order to do things like:


         original->nonNegHeader->value

Comment: You need pointers to the list nodes (these need to be const then for `original`), not for `original` itself (but you access `original` via `operator.` instead of `operator->`: `original.nonNegHeader->value`).

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown is not a proper copy constructor. For one thing, it doesn't take its input object by const reference, which is a requirement. For another, it doesn't set the `nonNegHeader` and `negHeader` members of the object being copied to. It constructs a 3rd object to copy into, and then leaks it.

Try something more like this instead:

```
InfiniteBools::InfiniteBools(const InfiniteBools& original)
    : nonNegHeader(NULL), negHeader(NULL)
{
    //sets the head of this to new linked list nodes that are copies of original

    LinkedListNode* tempOrig = original.nonNegHeader;
    LinkedListNode** tempCopy = &nonNegHeader;
    while (tempOrig) {
        // Allocate the next node and set current node next to the new node.
        *tempCopy = new LinkedListNode(tempOrig->value, NULL);
        tempCopy = &(tempCopy->next); //move temp to the new node
        tempOrig = tempOrig->next; //move temp of original forward
    }

    tempOrig = original.negHeader;
    tempCopy = &negHeader;
    while (tempOrig) {
        // Allocate the next node and set current node next to the new node.
        *tempCopy = new LinkedListNode(tempOrig->value, NULL);
        tempCopy = &(tempCopy->next); //move temp to the new node
        tempOrig = tempOrig->next; //move temp of original forward
    }
}
```